# Does the Microsoft update for BlackLotus mitigation SKUSiPolicy.p7b require Memory Integrity to be on and working in the Security Center?

Tags: security, windows-update, secure-boot, boot-manager, vulnerabilities

In other words is the "Code Integrity feature" [on this Microsoft kb5025885 page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb5025885-how-to-manage-the-windows-boot-manager-revocations-for-secure-boot-changes-associated-with-cve-2023-24932-41a975df-beb2-40c1-99a3-b3ff139f832d):

> The Code Integrity Boot Policy (SKUSiPolicy.p7b) uses the Code Integrity feature of Windows to prevent untrusted Windows boot managers from loading when Secure Boot is turned on.

... the same as the "Memory Integrity" discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-hvci-enablement)?

> Memory integrity is sometimes referred to as hypervisor-protected code integrity (HVCI)

**Info. about the PC:**

- In the Security Center > Device security, it says Secure boot is on, but "Standard hardware security not supported".
- The PC has Windows 10 (home) it is the only OS.

**Reason for asking:**

The above linked [kb5025885](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb5025885-how-to-manage-the-windows-boot-manager-revocations-for-secure-boot-changes-associated-with-cve-2023-24932-41a975df-beb2-40c1-99a3-b3ff139f832d) article says:

> it cannot be reverted if you continue to use Secure Boot

and [this kb5027455 page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb5027455-guidance-for-blocking-vulnerable-windows-boot-managers-522bb851-0a61-44ad-aa94-ad11119c5e91) says:

> the boot manager will “lock” the policy to the system by adding a variable to the UEFI firmware.

I'm cautious of enabling SKUSiPolicy.p7b and related updates, to see what would happen under these conditions, but seek to secure the machine as much as reasonably possible. If memory integrity is required and the update is enabled anyway, I don't know if the update just won't work, if only the DBX part would work, or if it could make the PC unbootable.

Comment: If you have installed the update (July 11, 2023), then Windows will continue to boot, if you implement the mitigation today. You will of course have to update any installation media you currently have to an ISO that contains the updated boot manager. The workaround for any potential Windows booting issues, after applying the protections ahead of the 2024 deadline, is to disable Secure Boot. `Code Integrity Boot Policy` != `Memory Integrity and VBS`

Comment: `Standard hardware security not supported` is caused by Core Isolation not being enabled which is yet another separate security feature.  Core Isolation likely cannot be enabled due to a driver.  Attempting to enable Core Isolation will give you insight into which driver that is exactly. To be exact `Memory Integrity` is part of Core Isolation and requires TPM 2.0 and Hypervisor (VT-x or AMD-V) support to be enabled.

Comment: Thanks, what would happen if I was to update media, then enable the updates for what I can get out of them considering there is no Memory Integrity, would it fail to boot, or break other things? If Secure boot has to be disabled to boot, can something be changed at that point to allow it to be re-enabled?  I'm wanting as much protection as possible. Would a backup in bios help with any of this?

Comment: Did you read the resolutions for issues after you have installed the mitigation?  Your question about Secure Boot is answer in that documentation, which I echoed, to suggest your system won't simply be unbootable as you will always have the option to tempoarlily disable Secure Boot.  If you are really worried wait till the automatic deployment.

Comment: Thanks, I did read it (in kb5025885?), thought it was for missing SKUSiPolicy.p7b or latest bootmgfw.efi after updating, rather than having applied the updates without having HVCI (result is unknown to me). If the "UEFI lock" described in kb5027455 is in place, and so is the Reg key to enable updates (3a. in kb5025885), can they be reverted if SecureBoot is temporarily disabled? Or could I be stuck without SecureBoot if the lack of HVCI is an issue? Waiting for auto deployment would mean I didn't have the update protection in the meantime, and any issue with it would happen then instead.

Comment: I cannot help you.